# Error while Install or Upgrade on 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, 20.04

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.When I upgrade or install something the package shared-mime-info takes long time to process.

when I run `sudo dpkg --configure shared-mime-info` I get output

```
 dpkg: error processing package shared-mime-info (--configure):
 package shared-mime-info is already installed and configured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 shared-mime-info
```